# Debug my SQL Server trigger update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

If I try the SQL statement with normal query, it works fine like this:

```
UPDATE TraineeMonthlyShopItemListRecord 
SET Data01 = 1
WHERE TraineeID = '553' 
  AND ShopItemListID = '17' 
  AND RecordID IN (SELECT a.recordid 
                   FROM TraineeMonthlyHourRecord a 
                   JOIN MonthlyHourRecord b ON a.RecordID = b.RecordID 
                   WHERE b.Month = '201609' 
                     AND a.TraineeID = '553' 
                   GROUP BY a.RecordID 
                   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

However it doesn't work in a trigger. I can successfully save the trigger but when I test it with manually insert a record in the table, I keep getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'MonthlyHourRecord'

Here is my trigger code, please have a look and see what could be wrongs, thanks!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[t2]
ON [dbo].[TraineeShopItemListRecord]
AFTER INSERT     
AS       
BEGIN
    declare @TraineeID varchar(10)
    declare @MM varchar(10)
    declare @YYYY varchar(10)
    declare @ShopItemListID varchar(20)
    declare @RecordID varchar(10)
    declare @YYYYMM varchar(10)
    declare @RecordTime datetime
    declare @DD varchar(10) declare @test varchar(10)
    declare @DataDD varchar(10)
    declare @Quantity varchar(10)
    declare @SQL nvarchar(200)

    SELECT @ShopItemListID = ShopItemListID from inserted
    SELECT @RecordTime = RecordTime from inserted
    SELECT @Quantity = Quantity from inserted

    SET @MM = substring(CONVERT(varchar,@RecordTime, 112),5,2)
    SET @YYYY = substring(CONVERT(varchar,@RecordTime, 112),1,4)
    SET @DD = substring(CONVERT(varchar,@RecordTime, 112),7,2)

    SELECT @TraineeID = TraineeID from inserted

    SET @YYYYMM = @YYYY+@MM
    SET @DataDD = 'Data'+@DD

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE TraineeMonthlyShopItemListRecord SET     '+@DataDD+'='+@Quantity+' WHERE  TraineeID ='''+@TraineeID+''' and ShopItemListID='''+@ShopItemListID+''' and RecordID IN (SELECT DISTINCT a.RecordID from TraineeMonthlyHourRecord a JOIN MonthlyHourRecord b on a.RecordID = b.RecordID WHERE b.Month ='''+@YYYYMM+''' and a.TraineeID ='''+@TraineeID+''' GROUP BY a.RecordID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 )'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL  
END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @Quantity = Quantity from inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What direction should I consider to rewrite it?

Comment: You need to take into account that `Inserted` (and `Deleted`) will contain **multiple rows** and thus you need to use **set-based** operations instead of fetching individual column values.

Comment: The error message is "Incorrect syntax near 'MonthlyHourRecord'", does my syntax near that position have problem to cause this error?

Comment: Your trigger is a mess! Why do use dynamic SQL if you can just join `inserted` and do the stuff. The trigger is on `TraineeShopItemListRecord` but where in a query do you use this table?

Answer (score 0):

To large for comment so I write it in an answer.

You can use this

```
SELECT  TraineeID,
        ShopItemListID,
        RecordTime,
        Quantity,
        substring(CONVERT(varchar,@RecordTime, 112),1,4)+substring(CONVERT(varchar,@RecordTime, 112),5,2) as YYYYMM
        'Data'+substring(CONVERT(varchar,@RecordTime, 112),7,2) as DataDD 
FROM inserted
```

To join with tables you need to update.

Give this a try:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  TraineeID,
        ShopItemListID,
        RecordTime,
        Quantity,
        substring(CONVERT(varchar,@RecordTime, 112),1,4)+substring(CONVERT(varchar,@RecordTime, 112),5,2) as YYYYMM
        'Data'+substring(CONVERT(varchar,@RecordTime, 112),7,2) as DataDD 
FROM inserted
)

UPDATE tm 
SET Data01 = c.Quantity
FROM TraineeMonthlyShopItemListRecord tm
INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.TraineeID = tm.TraineeID 
        AND tm.ShopItemListID = c.ShopItemListID
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT a.RecordID 
    FROM TraineeMonthlyHourRecord a 
    INNER JOIN MonthlyHourRecord b 
        ON a.RecordID = b.RecordID 
    WHERE b.Month = c.YYYYMM
        AND a.TraineeID = c.TraineeID 
    GROUP BY a.RecordID 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) a
WHERE a.RecordID = tm.RecordID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining.

Comment: My pleasure! Hope this will help you :)